# translate 'aa' to 'a' and 'ab' to 'b' in python

Tags: python, translate

i think it over night,but couldn't find a fast way to do it

first came to place is replace()

```
for x,y in {'aa':'a','ab':'b'}.items():
    s = s.replace(x,y)
```

but it won't work for this case:'aabcc'

correct is 'abcc'
but output would be 'bcc'

i can write some similar code like this (i have already write those code in various language like C#,php,actionscript,etc..)

```
   output = []
   def foo1(x):
      if(x!='a'):
          output.append(x)
      else:
          functionPointer = readafterA
   def readafterA(x):
      if(x=='a'):
          output.append('a')
      elif(x=='b'):
          output.append('b')
      else:
          output.append('a'+x)
      functionPointer = foo1
   functionPointer = normalExecute
   for singlechar in s:
      functionPointer(singlechar)
   print(''.join(output))
```

i don't want write those code any more ,becuz:

1st,those code would messed up when the dictionary go big.

2nd,i believe there has to be some more elegant ways to do this job in Python

**edit:** i have fixed it in first paragraph,but that was not the point.

Comment: I don't see what you're trying to do. Given your lists of input and output, it seems you just want to remove the first character.

Comment: You want something like [this](http://www.evaisse.net/2009/python-string-multi-replace-a-strtr-like-37002).

Comment: Your example using `replace` would need to be `s = s.replace(...)` to do anything at all.

Comment: alex,your solution works, great! i would give you the best answer,please explain more about the code.not very familiar with python and regular expressions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can just not use a dict. Specify the tuples in the order you want to substitute them.

```
>>> s = 'aabcc'
>>> for x,y in (('ab','b'), ('aa','a')):
...     s = s.replace(x,y)
... 
>>> s
'abcc'
```

You could also use regular expressions

```
>>> s = 'aabcc'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub("a([ab])","\\1", s)
'abcc'
```

Answer (score 0):

What is happening here is:

```
>>> "aabcc".replace("aa","a")
"abcc"
```

and at the next iteration:

```
>>> "abcc".replace("ab","b")
"bcc"
```

So, you need to change the logic.

I have a suggestion:

replace `"aa"` with `"^aa^"` and `"ab"` with `"^b^"`
then remove all unwanted `"^"`

now

```
>>> "aabcc".replace("aa","^a^")
"^a^bcc"
```

at the next iteration:

```
>>> "^a^bcc".replace("ab","b")
"^a^bcc"
>>> "^a^bcc".replace("^","")
"abcc"
```

cool eh?

Comment: this was not a common solution,what if there's ^ in an input?

Comment: use some other string which u expect never occure in your doc. eg "\replacement" instead of "^"